# IBM Mobilefirst IOS Push notification not receiving in Iphone?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I have tried to send push notification using IBM Mobilefirst and configured almost everything by this [doc](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/) but still i am not receiving push on ios. I am receiving push on android.

If i check with normal ios push script its also working i receive the push. So i deduce the problem is with mobilefirst server communicating with apple push server.

what do i have to do on serverside to check push server are open for mobilefirst?
[image]

What and all i have to check inorder for the push notification to work in mobilefirst server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what ports and addresses should be open in your IT infrastructure for push notification communication, then this is the list as described in: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/

*For push notifications to be sent, the following servers must be accessible from a MobileFirst Server instance:*

*Sandbox servers:

gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196*

*Production servers:

gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Feedback.push.apple.com:2196

1-courier.push.apple.com 5223*

Comment: how to check these server are accessible from my mobilefirst server. for some reason i m not receiving the apple push notification in my device. But in console it shown as sent. i m not seeing any in error so far.

Comment: It's not related to MFP server. It relates to your network.